# Azure Site recovery for SQL Server Azure VM

Tags: sql-server, database, azure

If there is a need to set up Azure site recovery for Azure VMs (which has SQL Server installed with Always On availability group installed), then how we can do it?

For a normal Azure VM, I can set up ASR. But if we follow same steps for VMs which have SQL Server and AG group configured, then on DR server will it work same as Primary VM?

Please share any link or blog which help to set it up.

Answer (score 0):

Happy to inform you that Azure provides the complete Disaster Recovery solution for your SQL Server VMs :)

[Always On availability groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/always-on-availability-groups-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) feature is a high-availability and disaster-recovery solution that provides an enterprise-level alternative to database mirroring. An availability group supports a failover environment for a discrete set of user databases, known as **availability databases**, that fail over together. Each set of availability database is hosted by an availability replica. Two types of availability replicas exist: **a single primary replica**. which hosts the primary databases, and **one to eight secondary replicas**, each of which hosts a set of secondary databases and serves as a potential failover targets for the availability group.

**The primary replica makes the primary databases available for read-write connections from clients. The primary replica sends transaction log records of each primary database to every secondary database.**

You can explore more **Business Continuity and Disaster Recover (BCDR)** technologies with Site Recovery options [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/site-recovery-sql#combining-bcdr-technologies-with-site-recovery).

To create an Always On availability group for SQL Server on Azure Virtual Machines (VMs), please follow [Manually configure an availability group (SQL Server on Azure VMs)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/virtual-machines/windows/availability-group-manually-configure-tutorial-single-subnet) tutorial.

Comment: Hi UtkarshPal,  Yes I have seen this  MS document. They asked to use some script for that. I do not found any exact steps to prepare ASR for two AG nodes SQL servers.

Comment: what script? can you please share the same?

Comment: Hi Utkarsh, Please have a look into below url. There some steps needs to be followed. Please have a look at step-3.                                             
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/site-recovery-sql